# Is everything cleaned up when using 'goto'?

Tags: c++, goto

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < 10 ; ++j)
    {
        goto label;
    }
}
label:
// stuff
```

After `goto` will the `i` and `j` variables get freed? From what I recall `goto` doesn't unwind the stack or do any cleanup so will it screw something up in this case?

Comment: Do you need `goto`? If you need the above function, add it in a function and use `return`

Comment: NEVER EVER use `goto`. Also you could check this for your self pretty easily.

Comment: @Jori, `goto` has its place, but here, a function is probably best.

Comment: This is one of the few cases where I find `goto` useful. The `break` keyword doesn't _break_ out of nested loops.

Comment: @Jori sometimes goto is appropriate to exit nested loops.

Comment: @Blastfurnace But `break` is just a goto in disguise.  You need it for the cases in a switch, but otherwise, it is best avoided as well.  As a general rule: `goto` and `continue`: never, `break`: only to end a case in a switch; `return` only as the last statement of a non-void function.  (There are a few exceptions, particularly with regards to the return, but overall, if you feel the need to violate the above rules, you've not thought the algorithm out thoroughly, or you've not broken the functions down enough.)

Comment: @JamesKanze These are terrible rules.

Comment: @NPS Unless you're trying to write code that actually works, reliably.

Comment: @JamesKanze Honest to God, what possible argument could you have against stopping execution of code earlier (in some cases only, of course) with `continue`, `break` or `return`?

Comment: @NPS Just that it's impossible to reason about the code if you do.  This is not a new concept; it was first argued by Dijkstra, 30 or 40 years ago.

Comment: `goto` has no place in clean code. Its perhaps sometimes useful to speed things up, but in the end you end up with sloppy code. There is NO excuse for `goto`.

Comment: @JamesKanze Care to elaborate? Links/sources would be nice.

Comment: The reference is _Structured Programming_, Dahl, Dijkstra and Hoare (ISMB 0-12-200550-3), despite its date (1972) still one of the most important texts a programmer should have studied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it gets cleaned up. Because C++ frees variables that go out of scope.